# How to show all jobs in sge(sun grid engine)

Tags: qsub

I used `apt` to install sge in my ubuntu 16.04 server.
Howerver, when I use `qsub` to submit a job, `qstat -j "*"` can only show error jobs and running jobs information.
Does `sge` has some command or options to show all jobs info（including success finished jobs）

Answer (score 0):

For terminated jobs, `qacct` should be used.

E.g. to show information about all jobs in the account file, use

```
qacct -j "*"
```

The `qacct` man page gives further information:
http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qacct.html